Sitecore - not able to send data from client side JS to C# backend
I have a requirement to build a custom dialog box in sitecore. I am facing an issue on OK button click where I need to send the user inputs to backend. In the client side JS i am using the below.
Sitecore.Shell.UI.SheerResponse.postMessage({
                    command: 'SendDataToServer',  // Custom command to handle data on the server
                    args: {
                        sourceLanguage: sourceLanguage,
                        targetLanguage: targetLanguage,
                        translatebox: translatebox
                    }
                });

I am able to see the recorded data in developer console but unable to send the data to backend. Its showing as :
"Sitecore is not defined" and pointing to  "
Sitecore.Shell.UI.SheerResponse.postMessage

"
I have tried to include the below js files in xml but it shows the same error for them as well :
<Script src="/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/core/2.0/sitecore.js" type="text/javascript" />
<Script src="/sitecore/shell/controls/Sitecore.js" type="application/javascript" />
<Script src="/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Common/SheerUI/SheerUI.js" type="text/javascript" />
<Script src="/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/ui/1.1/dialog.js" type="text/javascript" />

I am trying to send the captured data from sitecore client side js to backend using Sitecore.Shell.UI.SheerResponse.postMessage.
Any solution?
